# use tcpkill command from an ip list

Tags: bash

I have got an ip list in a file called ips: 
ip1
ip2

I want to tcpkill from this list. I cannot do it from tcpkill command options. I need a script which will write :

> tcpkill -i eth0 -9 host ip1 or host ip2

the list can grow in time.

the only thing I know is that I will need a loop to read the list:

> for IP in $(cat list) ; do
>   echo "tcpkill -i eth0 -9 host $IP " (for
>   the first element of the list)
>   echo "or host $IP" (for the rest of
>   the list).

So my questions are: 
1. what would be the right syntax for this purpose? 
2. Is there a completely different way of doing this?

Any idea folks ?!

thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This single line command would append the IP list to tcpkill command to form the complete command:

```
tcpkill -i eth0 -9 host $(cat list | xargs | sed 's/ / or host /g')
```

You can put this command after `echo` to see how the command gets formed.

```
echo tcpkill -i eth0 -9 host $(cat list | xargs | sed 's/ / or host /g')
```

Comment: thanks indeed Prasanna; could you please explain your code?

Comment: `cat list` prints all IPs on stdout. The next `xargs` command appends all lines of list to a single line with space separator. Now we have list of IP addresses with space as the separator (e.g. "ip1 ip2 ip3 ip4 ip5 ..."). The next `sed` command replaces each space with string " or host ". The "g" flag of sed command tells to replace all occurrences of space character by this string. As a result we get a string like "ip1 or host ip2 or host ip3 or host ip4 or host ip5". We append this string to `tcpkill` command at appropriate place after `host` word. Read about `$(cmd)` syntax for more info.